# Segfault with simple recursive openmp task

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, openmp, valgrind

I am trying to parallelize this recursive function with openmp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void rec(int from, int to){
    int len=to-from;
    printf("%X %x %X %d\n", from, to, len, omp_get_thread_num());
    if (len > 1){
        int mid = (from+to)/2;
        #pragma omp task
        rec(from, mid);
        #pragma omp task
        rec(mid, to);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    long len=1024;

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    rec(0, len);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it I get segfault:

```
$g++ -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic -lefence -g -O0 test.cpp && ./a.out
0 400 400 0
0 200 200 1
200 400 200 0
Segmentation fault
```

When I run it in valgrind it shows no errors. Without -lefence it also work.

I tried all possible combinations of #pragma omp clauses and it is either one-threaded or segfault.

What is wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You got seg fault for long len=1024;?

Comment: Probably, no. It segfault even for int len=20;

Comment: @JiříNádvorník Strange i test with 24 threads 1024 and it works fine. It is just this code you have?

Comment: Yes, exactly this code and commands. (With 2 threads, on 64bit machine, gcc 4.3.3). Time of segfault is nondeterministic. Every run it crash in different iteration.

Comment: Electric Fence (`libefence`) is known to conflict with some OpenMP runtimes. Link without it and use another memory checker (e.g. `valgrind`) instead. Check your stack size limits and run within `gdb` in order to locate the place where it crashes.